# All tasks has their own lifecycle | What methodology and tool suits?

Tags: jira

End user get multiple tasks which they are maintaining in Excel. There is no sprint or no stories i.e each task go to production separately and have its own life cycle

End user expect following:

```
Currently, we do not have task tracker.

We get requests for New Integrations, Change in existing Integrations, Incidents (many comes in service now where other comes in mailbox) and upgrades (system update or data cleanups or many such internal task)

As of now for New Integrations we are using Sharepoint for Data request and tracking. For others, we use Excel.
 So
-We can create task and put in backlog.
-Developer can assign to themselves, can comment on tasks, can attach documents to tasks, can ask queries
-A Board where we can track task status (To Do, In Prog, Test, QA, Prod etc.) till it is Done. 
-Can assign reassign like we do in Jira Boards.
```

What methodology does this fits into and tools to achieve same? As i understand that It is not agile.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.